# Why does iPhone screen stay lit causing significant drainage to the charge

Tags: iphone

Why does screen stay continuously lit causing  significant drain on the charge

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We are going to need a lot more detail to answer this question.  Can you clarify what you mean by "stay continuously lit"?  Also, it is very helpful to post what model iPhone you have, what version of iOS etc.  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.  Also, be sure to post any details to the **original question** so it's easier for others to find and read it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a setting - though some apps can override it & keep the phone active, particularly Sat Navs, where you don't want them to nod off all the time..

Settings > General > Auto-Lock ... from 30 seconds, through 5 minutes & Never.

[image]

Comment: Any app can override it, many have in-app options.